# SQLAlchemy Inheritance and returning proper subclasses

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

For background, this is part of a personal project I'm working on built with Flask, and hence Flask-SQLAlchemy. The concept that Artists have albums. Members have playlists. Albums and Playlists can both have tracks. To me, this sounds like a textbook case of inheritance -- Albums and Playlists are both just specific types of Tracklists. The logic's a little convoluted because I need to maintain separate track positioning markers for each individual tracklist; however, that's tangential to my actual question.

```
class Tracklist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tracklists'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(128), index=True)
    type = db.Column(db.Unicode(16))
    tracks = db.relationship('TrackPosition', backref='tracklist')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on' : type,
        'with_polymorphic' : '*'
        }

class Album(Tracklist):
    __tablename__ = 'albums'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tracklists.id'), primary_key=True)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artists.id'), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args_ = {
        'polymorphic_identity' : 'album',
        'inherit_condition' : (id == Tracklist.id)
        }

class Playlist(Tracklist):
    __tablename__ = 'playlists'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tracklists.id'), primary_key=True)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('members.id'), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args_ = {
        'polymorphic_identity' : 'playlist',
        'inherit_condition' : (id == Tracklist.id)
        }
```

I have back relations set on the Member and Artist models that specifically reference Playlist and Album. And they work as expected (if a bit cumbersome, but I haven't worked any association proxies in yet), for example:

```
atdi = models.Artist(name='At the Drive-In')
atdi.albums.append(models.Album(name='Relationship of Command'))
arcarsenal = models.Track(name="Arcarsenal", artist=atdi)
atdi.albums[0].tracks.append(models.TrackPosition(track=arcarsenal, position=1))
```

But when I ask `arcarsenal` what tracklists it belongs to, I don't get back Album or Playlist types. I get back Tracklist types. If I ask `atdi` what albums it has, I get back Album types. If I create a member with a playlist and add arcarsenal to it, I get back Playlist types when I go through Member but Tracklist through the Track model.

I've been combing over the documentation for joined table inheritance, looking at code examples and questions here; I feel like I'm right on the verge of figuring this out but I can't quite puzzle it because I've been looking at it for so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was pointed out that I am missing an underscore on the Album and Playlist models mapper args. :/ Imagine that.